# Vue3: How to get the state of component including all properties in the Vue error handler - Or how to convert vue component instance to plain object

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 with composition API and Bugsnag for error handling. When there is an error I want to send the entire state of the component where the error happened to bugsnag (i.e. the object I return from setup())

This is my code:

```
app.config.errorHandler = (error, instance, info) => {
    Bugsnag.notify(error, function (event) {
        event.addMetadata('instance', {...instance})
    })
}
```

It works perfectly locally but with this warning in the console: "Avoid app logic that relies on enumerating keys on a component instance. The keys will be empty in production mode to avoid performance overhead."

And just as the warning says, on production the object is empty.

So what is the correct way get all the properties from a component instance?

To give very clear examples here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/johnmellor2/pen/BavoVoa

And the code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <example></example>
</div>
```

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
})

app.config.errorHandler = (error, instance, info) => {
    console.log({...instance})
}

app.component('example', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="nonExistentThing()">
        Create Error
      </button>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    testprop: {
      type: String,
      default: 'foobar'
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const hello = 'hello world'
    
    return {hello}
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

You can see in the output I get exactly what I want but with the production warning:

```
{
  "testprop": "foobar",
  "hello": "hello world"
}
```

It doesn't have to be that exact structure it could be something like:

```
{
  props: {"testprop": "foobar"}
  data: {"hello": "hello world"}
}
```

It depends what's possible.

But hopefully the question is clear: How to get the state of component including all properties in the Vue error handler.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in the codepen you provided

Comment: Apologies it regularly seems to happen that I edit a codepen but it's not saved and the URL shows an older version. I've updated the codepen link to: https://codepen.io/johnmellor2/pen/BavoVoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, it seems like in vue3, all reactive objects are proxy objects. If you only need to get the `props` and `data`, it seems like you can use `toRaw` function from vue to make the proxy objects become raw object. So in the main.js file (or whatever you name it in your case, basically the file which contains the `createApp` function), you can modify it to this:

```
import { toRaw } from 'vue'

const app = Vue.createApp({
})

app.config.errorHandler = (error, instance, info) => {
  console.log({...toRaw(instance.$props), ...toRaw(instance.$.setupState)})
}

app.component('example', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="nonExistentThing()">
        Create Error
      </button>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    testprop: {
      type: String,
      default: 'foobar'
    }
  },
  setup() {
    const hello = 'hello world'
    
    return {hello}
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Additionally, if you use `<script setup>` instead of `setup()`, you must expose them instead of return them, e.g.:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

defineProps({
  testprop: {
    type: String,
    default: "foobar",
  }
})
const hello = "hello world"

defineExpose({
  hello
})
</script>
```

And then use this console.log:

```
app.config.errorHandler = (error, instance, info) => {
  console.log({...toRaw(instance.$props), ...toRaw(instance.$.setupState), ...toRaw(instance.$.exposed)})
}
```

Tried this in vue production mode and it works, [this is the forked codepen](https://codepen.io/damzaky/pen/VwqvVRp) if you need it.

Comment: Yes, all reactive objects are Proxies. It's in the docs. `reactive()` uses a proxy around the object you give it, and `ref()` assigns the value you give it to the `value` property of a reactive object.

Comment: Thankyou @Damzaky the real answer was in discovering $.setupState. I had tried using toRaw() but on the instance rather than that property. I can't seem to find any reference to $.setupState in the docs, I guess that means it's not something to be relied upon. But it certainly does answer my question and allow me to do what I wanted to.